# Opening of encrypted sparse bundle in El Capitan very slow

Tags: performance, macos, sparsebundle

I have a 76GB encrypted sparse bundle on the rMBP SSD drive. Mounting it by double clicking it in Finder was pretty much immediate in Yosemite.

With El Capitan a popup appears with "Verifying '*name of sparse bundle*'" and a progress bar. The progress bar shows no progress and after fifteen minutes or so the popup disappears and the password entry dialog box appears. After the password has been entered the sparse bundle is finally mounted.

When I run the Disk Utility First Aid function on the mounted volume it finishes in a few seconds and reports no errors. Console does not seem to show any related messages during the mounting.

Is there any reason why this popup appears and is there a way to circumvent it? Fifteen minutes to mount a volume is just not practical.

Comment: What is in the sparse bundle? if it's a Time Machine destination with multiple hard links, in the verification is going to be slow to matter what OS performs it and the upgrade could be coincidental and not causal...

Comment: It contains business data that is subject to NDA. No hardlinks.

Comment: Did you previously have image verification switched off? `defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages skip-verify -bool YES`

Comment: Not that I know of but I haven't done a fresh install since Leopard so possibly I have and El Cap turned it back on. I do think its unlikely I did though because if this data gets corrupted it would be a major pain.

Comment: You don't need to verify the image every time you open it... You can skip it. Just make backups of the disk image, and occasionally verify through Disk Utility.

Comment: It already goes to time machine so that part is covered. I'm leaning towards that I disabled the verify at some point because I can't find any other reports of similar cases. Google already picked this page up so I'll wait a bit to see if anyone with similar problems drops by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Sierra the password popup appears instantaneously. After entering the password the volume is available immediately. So for anyone else with this problem I'd say upgrade to Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a sparse bundle that was very slow (>1 minute) to mount, but I solved this (it now mounts in seconds) by **turning off automatic file system checking**. Before I figured it out, this would happen:

`hdiutil attach -verbose ~/the.sparsebundle` paused at this line:
`Checking volumes…`
and it would appear in Activity Monitor as `hdiutil` using 100% CPU, for over a minute at a time, depending on connection speed.

To speed things up, pass the `noautofsck` option to `hdiutil`, like so:
`hdiutil -noautofsck ~/the.sparsebundle`

Or if you are mounting any other way, **set the system preference**:
`defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages auto-fsck -bool NO`

It is possible your update to Sierra resulted in a default being reset and/or a bugfix, per the `hdiutil` man page:

> By default, only quarantined images (e.g. downloaded from the
>   Internet) that have not previously passed fsck are checked.

You could turn off the automatic file system checking and then check the output of `diskutil verifyVolume /Volumes/theSparseBundleVolume` occasionally, as a balance between data integrity and convenience. Keep in mind, that `diskutil` command will unmount your volume.